# Python 2.7.2 Multiple Values for one variable

Tags: python

I run my own business from home and started use Python 2 days ago. I'm trying to write a script that will search through my log files line by line and tell me if a system doesn't match my mandatory naming scheme. There are multiple different schemes and I want the script to look for them all. I've tried using a list (as seen below) but that won't work and then I tried with normal brackets and that gave me an error (requires left operand, not tuple). I've noted the lines that give me a problem.

```
    #variables
    tag = ["DATA-", "MARK", "MOM", "WORK-"] #THIS ONE!!!!!!

    #User Input
    print "Please select Day of the week"
    print "1. Monday"
    print "2. Tuesday"
    print "3. Wednesday"
    print "4. Thursday"
    print "5. Friday"
    print "6. Saturday"
    print "7. Sunday"
    day = input("> ")

    #open appropriate file and check to see if 'tag' is present in each line
    #then, if it doesn't, print the line out.
    if day == 1:
        f = open('F:\DhcpSrvLog-Mon.log', 'r')
        for line in f:
                if tag in line:  #THIS ONE!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                        pass
                else:
                        print line
```

Any tips or tricks would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest rewriting the code like this:

```
with open('F:\DhcpSrvLog-Mon.log', 'rU') as f:
    for line in f:
        for t in tag:
            if t in line: break
        else:
            print line
```

Using `with` you automagically close the file on exit of the block, so you needn't worry about forgetting to close it. Using `else:` in the for loop only triggers if you don't break out of the loop earlier.

Answer (score 1):

```
if day == 1:
    f = open('F:\DhcpSrvLog-Mon.log', 'r')
    for line in f:
            if tag in line:  #THIS ONE!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    pass
            else:
                    print line
```

replace with

```
if day == 1:
    f = open('F:\DhcpSrvLog-Mon.log', 'r')
    for line in f:
            if [x for x in tag if x in line]:  #THIS ONE!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    pass
            else:
                    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

use [any](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) to check this. It is more efficient because it will not try all the tags if it find that one is in line.

```
any(x in line for x in tag)
```

Comment: In fact, this is a better solution, b/c: "x in line for x in tag" is generator and any(...) will stop as soon as the first True value is found, compared to my solution: "if [x for x in tag if x in line]: ..."

Answer (score 0):

```
contains_tag=False
for t in tag:
    if t in line:
        contains_tag=True
        break # Found a match, break out of for loop

if not contains_tag:
    print (line)
```

First you need to loop through each of the tags (e.g. `for t in tag`). Then you need to check if the string `t` is contained in `line`.

Since you're only looking for one tag that does match, the simplest way is to keep track with a boolean variable.

If you wanted to only look for log messages that **start with** that tag, you could say `if line.startswith(t)` instead of `if t in line`

Comment: you don't need contains_tag flag. Use "for ...: ...; else: ..." construction. The "else" is only executed if no break was used in the for loop. Therefore, put print statement into "else" block.

Comment: "else" is available in both loops: while and for.